Spring data projection return TupleBackedMap instead of real result
I have following entities:
@Entity
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String num;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Group group;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Group {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String zone;
}

I want to retrieve all users nums with their zones using spring data jpa projection:
Here is my projection class:
public interface UserDtoProjection {

    String getNum();

    String getZone();
}

Here is my query:
@Query(value = "SELECT u.num as num, g.zone as zone FROM \"user\" u join \"group\" g on u.group_id = g.id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<UserDtoProjection> findAllUserZones();

but it doesn't return actual UserDtoProjection object, but TupleBackedMap. What may be the reason?

It's good that it returns TupleBackedMap. Using stream I could get num and zone like this:
findAllUserZones().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(UserDtoProjection ::getNum, UserDtoProjection ::getZone, (a, b) -> b));

